# Organizing favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

According to [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/what-is-the-mark-favorite-question-for) the marking a question as "favorite" is so that you can come back to it, i.e. it is sort of a bookmark. This is also how I have been using it, but for mainly two reasons:

1. I see a question that does not have a satisfactory answer and I think I know enough about the topic to **write an answer in the future**, but need to do some research first to make it sound.
2. A good answer/question that is useful to me and that I would like to **read and understand in more detail later**.

Now it turns out that the favorite tag is not actually very good for that. I marked a lot of questions that I could answer with favorite, but never got around to doing that. Now I can't find the questions that I wanted to read in detail anymore, cause they are buried in all the others. Of course that is really just my fault for using the feature in a stupid way. I was wondering though **how other people organize their favorite question?**

Furthermore would it be possible to **implement a feature that makes this organization easier?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so obvious that I hesitate to post it as an answer, but I deal with questions I want to answer but haven't the time right now by dragging a shortcut onto the desktop. Then I eventually delete them, unanswered, and wish I had more time :-)

Questions I want to keep for future reference I drag into a nested series of folders with the folder names acting a rudimentary catalogue.

Comment: haha i guess i'll start doing that then. was too focussed on finding a solution within the site... gotta think out of the box

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to "organize" your favorite, although that is an [open feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944/263383).

However, you *can* search your (or other users') favorites by adding `infavorites:<userid>` to a search term , where `<userid>` is, well, the user's ID (the number in the link to their profile). For your own favorites, you can substitute `mine` for `<userid>`. You can combine this with searching for tags (e.g. by adding `[quantum-field-theory]` to the search term) to quickly narrow down the list of stuff you have to scroll through. If you rememeber a specific keywords of the favorite you're looking for, even better - unless you favorite unusually many things, you'll get a modest amount of results.