# Introducing the possibility of creating folders in the favorites section

Tags: feature-request

It is my first question on meta, and I am not sure if this is the right place for this. 
I tried to see if it is possible to create folders in the section of favorites, to organise the related question in different topics. Personally I have saved different questions because I still can't understand them properly but many of these could really help me in future, but in this way the section gets quite confusing, allowing to create folders and name them could help to give a lot of order. 
I think this could be a good tool, obviously it is just a suggestion, I am not expecting anything but if it is something that a big part of the community would appreciate maybe could be considered. Thanks a lot

[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347480/introducing-the-possibility-of-creating-folders-in-favorites-section) is the same discussion open on MSE as indicated

Comment: This is an issue that effects all sites on the network, so it belongs on MSE. However, there are already some (ancient) questions about this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15504/334566 & the duplicate  target it links to. Also, there *are* improvements in store for the Favorites system, but I can't remember exactly where I read about that...

Comment: [This MSE announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345148/334566) mentions that Favorites will be renamed to Bookmarks. Maybe I was just imagining that it will be improved...

Comment: thanks a lot, I have read the announcement but unfortunately it doesn't cover this kind of situation. Anyway should i move this post to MSE or I should delete it as it is a duplicate?

Comment: We dont close a question if it's a duplicate of a question on another site. However, if you move this question to MSE, it is very likely to get closed as a dupe of one of those questions I linked earlier. I don't think it's a dupe of a question here on Physics meta, but it is closely related to this: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7752/123208

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proposal concerns the underlying Q&A engine that powers all of the Stack Exchange network, so the best venue for it is the [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) network-wide meta. However, that doesn't mean that it is off-topic here -- and, indeed, posting it here allows for a useful gauge of support from this site's community. SE is currently [restructuring its process for taking up user feedback on metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344586/our-commitment-to-responding-to-meta-and-moderators) and it's important to take them up on the opportunity.

As mentioned in the comments, the ability to organize the Favorites list is [a long-standing feature request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements-search-categorize-personal-tags-add-note-favorite-a), and [has also been suggested on this meta previously](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7752/organizing-favorite-questions). However, I would treat those threads as valuable historical resources, and instead look to the future: again as mentioned in comments, the dev team is [currently implementing the ability to 'follow' questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345148/upcoming-feature-follow-questions), and that effort includes <s>on its mid-term future goals</s> [as a just-rolled out development](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347558/favorites-are-now-known-as-bookmarks) a restructuring of the Favorites section, which <s>will be</s> has been renamed as Bookmarks.

So, now is a perfect time to put a word in for this feature, and hope for support. One good place would be as an answer to [the original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345148/upcoming-feature-follow-questions), but this is now closed as a duplicate of [the rollout announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network), and I don't think an answer there would be useful. I suspect the best way to go about this is to post a new [feature-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) on MSE pointing to all of these precedents, and asking explicitly for this feature to be built into the next dev cycle. There's no need to close this thread -- just edit in a link to the MSE thread here if you do post there.

Comment: thanks a lot, this seems a good idea, i'll do it as soon as possible by today

Comment: @Frappa Quick update regarding [this development](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347558/favorites-are-now-known-as-bookmarks). I've asked about their future plans regarding organization [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347589/184688).

Comment: I have seen it, thanks a lot for the support